# Как сделать так, что бы можно было ввести переменную N с клавиатуры, а не менять её в компиляторе?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand((int)time(0));
    const int N=20; //Кол-во прямоугольников
    double xTop[N], yTop[N], xBottom[N], yBottom[N]; //Координаты прямоугольников
    int i;
    double sMin;
    int NoSmin;
    printf("Координаты прямоугольников:\n");
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        xTop[i]=0.1*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        yTop[i]=0.2*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        xBottom[i]=0.5*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        yBottom[i]=0.7*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        printf("Прямоугольник %d: (%lf, %lf)-(%lf, %lf)\n", i+1, xTop[i], yTop[i], xBottom[i], yBottom[i]); //Выведение в консоли номера прямоугольника с его координатами
        double dX=fabs(xBottom[i]-xTop[i]); 
        double dY=fabs(yBottom[i]-yTop[i]);
        if (i==0)
            sMin=dX*dY;  //Нахождение площадей
        else
            if (sMin>dX*dY)  //Нахождение площадей
            {
                sMin=dX*dY;  //Нахождение площадей
                NoSmin=i+1;  //Нахождение площадей
            }  
    }
    printf("\tПрямоугольник с макс. площадью: %d\n",NoSmin); //Вывод в консоль прямоугольника с наибольшей площадью
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<double>::size_type N; cin >> N; std::vector<double> xTop(N);`

Answer (score 1):

Так устроит?

```
int N; //Кол-во прямоугольников
cin >> N;
double *xTop = new double[N], *yTop = new double[N], *xBottom = new double[N], *yBottom = new double[N];
```

Comment: Теперь выдаёт ошибку в части кода xTop[i]=0.1*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        yTop[i]=0.2*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        xBottom[i]=0.5*(rand()%100);  //Определение координат прямоугольников
        yBottom[i

Comment: Тьфу, написал по привычке `int`. Понятно, что `double`.